# Reading 30GB file using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to read a file a huge file of 30GB(25 million lines). I want to write a code which will create a thread pool and each thread will read 1000 lines in parallel (first thread would read first 1000 lines, second thread would read next 1000 and so on).
I have read the entire file and created thread pool but now I am stuck as to how can I ensure that each thread reads only 1000 lines and also keep track of the line numbers that been read so that the next thread does not have to read those lines.

Comment: Once you solve that problem, are you using magnetic drives? Regardless, this is going to be IO bound.

Comment: Having 1 thread read a large chunk (30GB) will normally be faster than having 25000 threads read small chunks. There is a lot of overhead on 25000 threads, and if it is 1 file that resides on 1 disk, then each thread will have to wait for access time in queue.

Comment: You should usually only have one thread manipulating an external resource such as a file. Instead of trying to distribute the I/O, which won't improve performance, have the reader thread post each bundle into a concurrent queue and/or send it to an executor task.

Comment: if the processing of the lines is slow on a single thread, you could read the data on one thread but then distribute the processing of the already read data to separate threads.

Comment: You can read millions of lines a second with `BufferedReader`, *ergo* you should be able to read this file in a few seconds. The disk is not multithreaded, so adding threads won't make this any faster. The overhead here will not be reading the file, it will be whatever processing you have to do per line.

Comment: Your problem is the classic producer-consumer problem in disguise. What you need is _one_ "producer" thread that writes a thread-safe queue (say an ArrayBlockingQueue) and bunch of "consumer threads" that _concurrently_ remove the elements from that queue and process them. The assumption here is that "processing" of the items in the queue takes time and you want to utilize the CPU's on your computer via multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

A. If it's acceaptable all threads have approximately equal number of lines, you can:

1. Assume the thread pool size is N, 1st thread seeks to file offset 0 and read [0, 30GB/N), 2nd thread seeks to offset 30GB/N, read [30GB/N, 30GB/N*2) etc.
2. The 2nd thread may not at the beginning of a line, but at the middle of a line. It's ok. Just skip the paritial line, and read the complete line. The 1st thread may ends with partial line. It's ok, just keep reading until read the '\n'. the remaining threads do the same thing.

B. If all threads must have exactly euqal number of lines, that's say 1000 lines, you can:

1. Have one thread read the whole file, build the index map. The map has the information like line0~line999 starts at offset 0, line1000~line1999 starts at offset 13521, etc...
2. All the threads read the files from the accordingly offset, and read 1000 lines.

Approach A reads the file 1 time. Approach B reads the file 2 times.

With approach A or B, you can have all threads processing the file(transforming, extracting, cleaning..) parallelly. But if processing is very fast, the bound is disk speed. Then your application is IO bound. You should just have one thread read the file and do the processing serially.

Comment: Approach B is the logic I pursued but then landed up with a problem of sharing line numbers which are already read between the threads. The single thread which reads the file puts the file contents in a queue and then it gets troublesome to read the queue for specific lines at the same time maintaining a thread safe counter to indicate the lines already read

Comment: You say "first thread would read first 1000 lines" I thought the group of the lines must be processed together. If there's no such constraint, just read first small N(1, 2, is ok) lines and give to 1st thread, and second small N lines to give to 2nd thread. etc.

Comment: @ChristineDsouza You already have the approach. Just show us your code and your question about thread safe issue.

Comment: The group of lines need to processed together. So i need to create threads which would read 1000 lines and complete the further processing but i need the threads to be executed in parallel and do not have any wait time.

Comment: Code is added and my question is that the threads read the file in parallel but they read the lines till end of file. I want each thread to read only a fixed number of lines eg. 1000 (so first thread reads lines from 1 to 1000, second thread reads from 1001 to 2000 and so on and in parallel) and then have new threads continue this process till end of file is reached